# Return class name in which a static method resides

Tags: c#, static-methods

Consider the following code:

```
public class MyClass
{
     public static string MyStaticMethod()
     {
          //string className = GetClassNameHere...
     }
}
```

Is it possible to get the name of the class in which the static method resides ? Due to the fact that im using a static method, it is not possible to use the this pointer to retrieve the type of the object that im currently working in.

Comment: Pls elaborate what do you mean by "this pointer"

Comment: @AB Kolan: I assume Russel is referring the keyword "this".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try the following

```
return typeof(MyClass).Name;
```

Or also

```
return MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this...

```
String className = typeof(MyClass).Name;
```

Answer (score 2):

I may be missing the point entirely here, but what's wrong with the string "MyClass"?

```
public class MyClass
{
     public static string MyStaticMethod()
     {
          string className = "MyClass";
          Console.WriteLine(className);
     }
}
```

You may argue that if MyClass is inherited, you would want the name of the inherited class instead. Then consider the following:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static string MyStaticMethod()
    {
        string className = typeof(MyClass).Name;
        Console.WriteLine(className);
    }
}
public class MyOtherClass : MyClass{ }
```

Now, what do you think you will see in the Console if you invoke `MyOtherClass.SomeMethod`? The answer is "`MyClass`". So, looking up the class name dynamically will give you the exact same result as simply typing it in a string. The only upside I can see with getting it through Reflection is that it will still render the correct result if you rename the class.

Comment: He might want it to be refactoring-safe. And for inheritance of course, though that's tricky.

Comment: It may be a rather good performance penalty for keeping it safe for refactoring. And as I point out in my answer, there is no inheritance upside since it is a static method; it will always return the name of the base class.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MethodBase m = MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod();
            MemberInfo info = (MemberInfo)m;
            Console.WriteLine(info.DeclaringType.FullName);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

The console will show "ConsoleApplication1.Program" =)

Comment: OP is looking for the class name, not the method name.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't need to cast to MemberInfo. m.Name should be enough.

Comment: @JaredPar - Yup, I realised my bad, d'oh =)